# Web Browsers print only loaded Images

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, printing

I'm working on a website project (Typo3) and the following problem is occurring.

Web Browsers (Tested with Chrome n' Firefox) only show Images in the Print Preview which are loaded. 
So, if I land on a Page and don't scroll to the bottom and print, no or just a few Images are displayed in the Print Preview.

But if I first scroll to the bottom of the page before I print, all Images are displayed correctly in the Print Preview. So, the images has to be or been visible in the Browser before the browser is able to print it.

Is there a way to "preload" all Images automatically, so that I can print correctly without having to scroll to the bottom first?

Edit:
It's the same when I use 'window.print();' as when I use Ctrl+P.

Comment: do you have any console error in browser, or can i see your development url. ?

Comment: No Error is displayed in the Console.
I don't want to write here the URL of my project. 

But I could find [this Website](http://www.20min.ch/) with the same Problem. 
If you don't scroll down and print, you have less Images as when you scroll down and print.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found it. It was the Bootstrsp Package for Typo3.
It uses Lazyload and has set the Image Preload on false.

I set it on true and everything is working fine now.